# ¿como eliminar palabras de un dataframe a partir de las de una lista?

Tags: python, regex, bucles

He creado un dataframe del que quiero eliminar palabras que coloco en una lista.

```
datos = {'compromiso' : ['juan tiene (un) el 50% del área', 'camilo vende el 50% del área', 'se oferta un 40% del area']}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
```

para esto he creado un ciclo for que recorre mi dataframe, pero al correr mi código me sale este error:
---> 11     string = ''.join( x for x in string if x not in quitar)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

no sé por qué

```
for index in range(df.shape[0]):
    string = index
    lista=["(un)","50","%","40"]
    for indice in lista:
        quitar=indice
        string = ''.join( x for x in string if x not in quitar)
```

Estaré muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Si tienes la opción de tu crear el iterable a reemplazar (La lista con las palabras) podrías sustituirla por un diccionario y utilizar [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
import pandas as pd

datos = {'compromiso' : ['juan tiene (un) el 50% del área', 'camilo vende el 50% del área', 'se oferta un 40% del area']}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
lista={'\(un\)':'','50':'','%':'','40':''}
df = df.replace({'compromiso': lista},regex=True)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    compromiso
0   juan tiene el del área
1   camilo vende el del área
2   se oferta un del area
```

La ventaja de utilizar este método es que si en cualquier momento desearas reemplazar por palabras diferentes en lugar de todas por una misma podría hacerse muy fácilmente al cambiar el diccionario y puedes trabajar por columnas por separado.

**Nota:** Hay que escapar los paréntesis para que puedan ser reemplazados de forma correcta, por eso en el diccionario es `\(un\)`

Ahora, si en verdad lo quieres hacer con una sola lista y reemplazar todo por el mismo `string` (Aunque sea vacío) puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = {'compromiso' : ['juan tiene (un) el 50% del área', 'camilo vende el 50% del área', 'se oferta un 40% del area']}
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
lista=['\(un\)','50','%','40']
r = r'({})'.format('|'.join(lista))
df = df.replace(r, '',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [apply y lambda](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applying-lambda-functions-to-pandas-dataframe/) a la columna de tu df, y luego utilizar el join que propusiste, pero teniendo en cuenta que es una oración, para tomar cada palabra de la misma, puedes hacer uso de `split()`.
Y el código quedaría asi..

```
df['new_col'] = df['compromiso'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(palabra for palabra in x.split() if palabra not in lista))
```

Aca el incoveniente es que en tu lista de palabras a eliminar pusiste "50" y "%" y al hacer .split() tomaría `50%` junto. Para solventar esto se puede hacer directamente un `replace()` a la hora de consultar si la palabra está en la lista, y quedaría así:

```
df['new_col'] = df['compromiso'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(palabra for palabra in x.split() if palabra.replace('%','') not in lista))
df['new_col'] 
0      juan tiene el del área
1    camilo vende el del área
2       se oferta un del area
Name: compromiso, dtype: object
```